# Showing that $\| f \|_2 = \int_a^b f(x)^2\mathrm{d}x$ indeed defines a norm.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

**Exercise :**

> Over $C[a,b]$, we define the norm :
>   $$\| f \|_2 = \int_a^b f(x)^2\mathrm{d}x$$
>   Show that $\| \cdot \|_2$ indeed defines a norm.

**Attempt :**

It's easy to prove $\| \cdot \|_2 \geq 0$, as :

$$\| f \|_2 = \int_a^b f(x)^2\mathrm{d}x \geq 0 \; \forall f \in C[a,b]$$

with $\| f \|_2 = 0$ for :

$$\|f\|_2 = 0 \Leftrightarrow \int_a^b f(x)^2\mathrm{d}x = 0 \Leftrightarrow f(x) = 0 $$

Now, it is :

$$\| \lambda f\|_2 = \int_a^b(\lambda f(x))^2\mathrm{d}x =\int_a^b \lambda^2f(x)^2\mathrm{d}x = \lambda^2\int_a^bf(x)^2\mathrm{d}x = \lambda^2\|f\|_2 \neq \lambda \|f\|$$

What's the issue here ? It seems that $\|\lambda f\|_2 \neq \lambda \|f\|_2$.

Also, for the triangle inequality, it is :

$$\|f+g\|_2 = \int_a^b(f+g)^2(x)\mathrm{d}x = \int_a^b(f(x)^2 + 2f(x)g(x) + g(x)^2)\mathrm{d}x$$

$$= \int_a^b f(x)^2\mathrm{d}x + \int_a^b 2f(x)g(x)\mathrm{d}x + \int_a^b g(x)^2\mathrm{d}x = \|f\|_2 + \int_a^b2f(x)g(x)\mathrm{d}x+\|g\|_2  $$

Now, I fail to see why would this be $\leq \|f\|_2 + \|g\|_2$.

**Please assist me in understanding and solving the issues above.**

Comment: Didn't you miss out a square root?

Comment: @Botond No, no square root in the defined norm.

Comment: Then it's not a norm as you showed.

Comment: @ZacharySelk The exercise demands to show that it indeed is a norm.

Comment: Then the exercise is impossible, because it is not a norm.

Comment: Well, it is not. The general theory (Cauchy-Schwarz) gives that $\sqrt{\int_{a}^{b}f(x)^2\,dx}$ fulfills the triangle inequality. To ask that such thing *and* its square *both* fulfill the triangle inequality is simply to ask too much.

Comment: The $L^2$ norm is $\|f\|_2=\sqrt{\int |f|^2}$, which is indeed a norm. But because the lack of the square root, $\|\lambda f\|_2 \neq |\lambda|\|f\|_2$ in general.

Comment: Bleh, I assume the professor missed out on the square root.

Comment: Or he/she wanted to write/say $\|f\|_2^2=\int f^2$.

Comment: The next questions want us to prove that if a sequence $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ with respect to $\| \cdot \|_\infty$ then it converges to $f$ with respect to $\| \cdot \|_2$ as well. In this case what is the norm required, so I can correct the exercise and proceed to solve it for practicing sakes ?